# PageSpeed issue Leverage browser caching for Google and Facebook external sources

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

We are currently improving our site's Google Pagespeed score and one of the very few remaining items left is the below issue:

Leverage browser caching

- https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga_exp.js?utmxkey=xxxxxxxxx&utmx=&utmxx=&utmxtime=xxxxxxxxx
- https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxxxxxx
- https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/xxxxxxxxx?v=2.8.27&r=stable
- https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js
- https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js

As you can see, PageSpeed is suggesting to cache the mentioned files, but they are external sources.
This is a WordPress site by the way, and I did try what seems like an experimental plugin to host locally the Google Analytics file, but it doesn't help.
I also tried locally hosting conversion.js - creating a copy of the file, saving it to my server, and referencing to that file instead but it breaks Google Analytics' A/B testing.

Are there any ways to address these PageSpeed issues?